# CKAN Filedownload with API

Tags: python, python-2.7, download, ckan

ive set up a ckan-server with all necessary plugins.
There is some content on the server (.csv-files).
Now id like to download a specific .csv-file to change it locally and upload it again.

But I dont have an idea how to download the complete file with the ckan-API.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think people hunting for the answer to the same question would appreciate you improving the title to this question. How about "How to use the CKAN API to download a data file?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `package_show` API call will tell you the URL for the CSV so that you can download it.

e.g. this dataset: http://data.gov.uk/dataset/uk-open-access-non-vosa-sites
is available on the API at: http://data.gov.uk/api/action/package_show?id=uk-open-access-non-vosa-sites
which results in something like:

```
{
  "help": "http://data.gov.uk/api/3/action/help_show?name=package_show",
  "success": true,
  "result": 
  {
    "name": "uk-open-access-non-vosa-sites",
    "license_title": "UK Open Government Licence (OGL)",
    "resources": [
        {
            "description": "A list of Authorised Testing Facilities (ATFs) and DVSA test stations ",
            "format": "CSV",
            "url": "http://dft.gov.uk/vosa/images/Find%20your%20nearest%20ATF%20or%20VOSA%20test%20station.csv",
            "id": "bd9aaa9f-2a9c-45f8-8246-6b99dd78208a",
            "resource_type": "file",
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

from which you can see the url is `http://dft.gov.uk/vosa/images/Find%20your%20nearest%20ATF%20or%20VOSA%20test%20station.csv` which you can download e.g. using wget:

```
wget http://dft.gov.uk/vosa/images/Find%20your%20nearest%20ATF%20or%20VOSA%20test%20station.csv
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. i was searching for something like this url for ages.